# When should I use "turn" over "turn into"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

> Yes, it did affect the yearly kernel summit last year (and this year
> is still up in the air), and most conferences got cancelled or **turned**
> virtual.

I'd like to know when should I use *"turn"* over *"turn into"* on the phrase cited above and why?

Could I even use *"turn into"*? Because I'm not sure too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use **turned into** in that sentence.

**turn** *adjective* means something like "become":

> When he saw the blood, he **turned** pale.

**turn into** *noun* means something like "change into a different thing":

> Caterpillars **turn into** butterflies.

So in this sentence, we know that we have to use **turn** and not **turn into**, because **virtual** is an adjective.  We could rephrase it to use **turn into** and a noun phrase, like

> Conferences got turned into virtual events

but usually "turn into" implies becoming a different thing, and in this case it seems less fluent because a virtual conference is still a conference.

Answer (score 0):

*Turn into* is followed by a noun phrase, so *turn into virtual* would not be grammatical.

*Turn* may be followed by an adjective; but not all adjectives work. I would find *turn virtual* odd in most contexts.

But note that this example is not *turn (into)* but *get turned (into).* This is passive, and it works here because it implies there is somebody doing the "turning", whereas intransitive *turn* implies that something changes of its own accord.